# Extend domain to closed interval to make f continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Given $f:(a,b) \to (a,b)$ and $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$, can we extend  domain to $[a,b]$ and state it still is continuous, because we take $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ accordingly?

Comment: $f(x)=1/x$ on $(0,1)$?

Comment: Aha, thanks @DavidMitra

Answer (score 0):

No, but there are conditions that you can impose on $f$ so it does happen ($f$ is Lipschitz continuous, etc).